# Macports Drush Conflict

Tags: macos, macports, drupal

Trying to install drush (Drupal Shell) with macports I get an error:

`Error: Unable to execute port: Can't install php52 because conflicting ports are installed: php5 php5-gd php5-iconv php5-mbstring`

There's only one blog I can find about a fix for this ([here](http://churchofchai.blogspot.de/2010/03/installing-drush-on-macports.html)):

```
$ sudo port deactivate php5
$ sudo port install drush
$ sudo port deactivate php52
$ sudo port activate php5
$ sudo pear install Console_Table-1.1.3
$ drush
```

However for me: `sudo port deactivate php5` gives:

`Error: port deactivate failed: Please uninstall the ports that depend on php5 first`

Any other ideas?

...I'd prefer not to go the Homebrew route as everything else I have installed via Macports.

I believe the version of Drupal I need to use is 6, but `sudo port install drush +drupal6` returned the same conflict as above.

Answer (score 2):

no need to go to *Homebrow* ...

To find the port depending on `php5` , use `port echo depends:php5`.

This may be because of a **leaf**, try `port echo leaves` and if not necessary `port uninstall leaves`.

If all this did not solve your problem, You can try this :

```
sudo port uninstall php5
sudo port install php52
sudo port install drush
```

Otherwise try installing a variant of `drush`using the following command :

`sudo port install drush +drupal5` or `sudo port install drush +drupal6`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - I had a lot of leaves in my ports tree which I have uninstalled. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue deactivating the port.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to downgrade as I am on php 5.3 and need it for other projects.

Comment: You are interested in which Drupal version ? 5 or 6 ?

Comment: updated my solution, please consider [faq](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Doh! `+drupal6` didn't work. Sorry I got excited and thought it had at first! I believe the project is Drupal6 but this is my first time setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the Pear channel:

```
pear channel-discover pear.drush.org
pear install drush/drush
```